# vnc to kvm host not working despite succesfull network connection

Tags: vnc, openstack

I have a centos 6.4 box running openstack grizzly. I have various instances running, yet I can not view their console. Horizon has a built in console viewer called novnc-proxy, which is not working either. For debugging purposes I try to connect to the vnc port directy. I have a network connection, but can not see any output.

The compute host has instances:

```
$ virsh list
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
  81    instance-0000010d              running
 82    instance-0000010e              running
 84    instance-00000110              running
 85    instance-00000111              running
```

They have a vnc port open:

```
 $ virsh vncdisplay 85
:9
```

The port is listet as open:

```
$ ss -l |grep -v 127.0.0.1 |grep 590
LISTEN     0      1                       *:5907                     *:*       
LISTEN     0      1                       *:5908                     *:*       
LISTEN     0      1                       *:5909                     *:*
```

I can connect to that port from outside using telnet:

```
$ telnet 192.168.10.140 5909
Trying 192.168.10.140...
Connected to 192.168.10.140.
Escape character is '^]'.
RFB 003.008
```

I can connect to that port with [remmina](http://remmina.sourceforge.net/), which then is listet as an established connection:

```
$ ss |grep 5909
ESTAB      0      0          192.168.10.140:5909        192.168.10.117:52172
```

Still I don't see anything. What is going on here?

Comment: Can you please show the contents of `/etc/sysconfig/vncserver` ?

Comment: It turns out is is a client issue ... I can view console with gtkvncviewer. Not sure whats bugging remmina.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this short script I wrote, I use it when deploying many servers:

```
#!/bin/bash
yum install pixman pixman-devel libXfont tigervnc-server.x86_64 -y
cat <<EOF > /etc/sysconfig/vncservers
VNCSERVERS="6:root"
VNCSERVERARGS[6]="-geometry 1152x864"
EOF
chkconfig vncserver on
/usr/bin/vncpasswd
/etc/init.d/vncserver start
```

During the script run you will be asked to set the VNC password and when it finishes you'll be able to connect to the server like so: `#vncviewer hostname:5906`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out is is a client issue ... I can view console with gtkvncviewer. Not sure whats bugging remmina.

Comment: It would seem that tigervnc (and I assume gtkvncviewer) will kick any other existing connection when connecting, but remmina does not. 

I can connect with xtigervncviewer, then close it, then immediately after that, remmina will connect. That is, until the libvirt viewer running on the host re-connects. Then remmina is blocked again.